# Encountered a task during an online python course (provided by EPAM) that I simply cannot solve

Tags: python

I am complete newbie to Python and to coding in general. I'm trying to learn a new skill.
This is my first time writing here so this might be a bit long.
I'm currently doing an online course at EPAM. It's a self-paced Python course for absolute beginners. Up until this point, I was doing fine (admittedly with the frequent help of ChatGPT) but I've encountered a task that I'm just unable to solve.
The task:

**"Implement a function that works the same as str.split method (without using str.split itself, of course). Pay attention to strings with multiple spaces. For example:"**

This is what I (with AI help) managed to write:

```
def split(data: str, sep=None, maxsplit=-1):
    result = []
    splits = 0

    while maxsplit != 0:
        if sep is None:
            index = next((i for i, c in enumerate(data) if c.isspace()), -1)
        else:
            index = data.find(sep)

        if index == -1:
            break

        result.append(data[:index])
        data = data[index + (1 if sep is None else len(sep)):]
        splits += 1

        if maxsplit > 0:
            maxsplit -= 1

    if data:
        result.append(data)

    return result
```

Test case:

```
print(split('Python    2     3', maxsplit=1))
```

It prints: `['Python', '   2     3']`, but the expected result is: `['Python', '2     3']`

There are other test cases involving special characters as separators, but I haven't even got there as I just can't seem to do anything with those extra spaces before the number 2.

Any ideas on what might be the issue and how to solve it?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Publishing content generated by ChatGPT et al. (not only answers) [isn't allowed currently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: When `sep` is not specified, multiple adjacent spaces should be treated as one split.  But you're incrementing `splits` after finding the first space.

Comment: John Gordon - thank you for the answer. I'll look into it.

Comment: In general, I wouldn't recommend using ChatGPT if you're an absolute beginner. Learning fundamental concepts is more important to your future knowledge as a programmer, than if you just get them from a computer, because it will become inconvenient.